# How to limit a specific apps maximum memory usage

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, ram

I have an app that I'm using (basic dreams) for a lock screen background, and it appears to have a memory leak. It has reached a peak of almost 800mb in ram, and I only have two GB. Is there a way to limit it's maximum ram usage without actually killing it/force closing it, because it has to always be on. I can upload a screen shot if necessary. O can't find any apps related besides "ram boosters" which I know are unnecessary. Any advice? Thanks,

(This is on android marshmallow/6.0, cyanogenmod 13 rooted)

-J

Comment: You can use tasker and set it up such that the app is closed every one minute and then restarted again.

Comment: @adeen-s Well I guess that would work for a normal app, but I want to know if there's a way to actually limit its ram and let it run forever in the background, because its my lock screen.

Comment: there isn't anything that you can do as user. The developer of the application needs to fix it. Look at this answer, or rather get the developer to look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9428660/1369016

Comment: Thank you, I wish I could ask the developer but its no longer supported (basic dreams). I guess I'll have to learn to build my own app ;)